# Handling an array in PHP

Tags: php

I have an array that looks like this:

```
 array(10) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "1.pdf"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "2.pdf"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "3.pdf"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "4.pdf"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "5.pdf"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "6.pdf"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "7.pdf"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "8.pdf"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "9.pdf"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "10.pdf"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "11.pdf"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "12.pdf"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "13.pdf"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "14.pdf"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "15.pdf"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "16.pdf"
  }
  [8]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "17.pdf"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "18.pdf"
  }
  [9]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "19.pdf"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "20.pdf"
  }
}
```

As you can see my array of 10 consists of an array of 2 elements.  What I'm needing to do is create a round robin if you will in that I have 3 folders where I'm needing to stuff [0]array(2) into FOLDER A then in FOLDER B stuff [2]array(2) and then in FOLDER C stuff [4]array(2) AND HERE IS THE KICKER, then go back to FOLDER A and stuff [1] into FOLDER A and then in FOLDER B stuff [3]array(2) and then in FOLDER C stuff [5]array(2) and then make another round round robin.  I'm having a really hard time getting my head around this and wondered if anyone could lend some help with this.

Any help/direction would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.=.

Comment: I don't really understand what's the expected result is.

Comment: Sorry, I am needing to take each set of 2 pdf files in each of the 2nd arrays and stuff them in each folder as I described above.  I'm not sure how to be more clear, sorry.

Comment: Round robin meaning circling back to FOLDER A from FOLDER C.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
$arr = [ ... ]; // pretend this is your big array

for ($i = 0, $total = count($arr); $i < $total; ++$i) {
    $folder = chr(floor($i / 2) + ord('A'));

    // Here you would put elements from the sub-array $arr[$i]
    // into folder $folder
}
```